# Login loop 19.10 extended problems

Tags: login, loop-device

Struck at login loop 19.10 running on dual boot Lenevo ideapad
Core i5 8th gen no external graphics.
This is what I have tried so far..
Alt ctrl F5 , 
1)
reconfigured and selected gdm3 and lightdm
Tried both at each boot 
2)
Tried to change Xauthority file using grep can't seem to find it anywhere
Tried this as well
3)
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"  with update-grub
I couldn't find anymore solutions to this problems 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Unless you made a change (added/changed video drivers, made configuration changes related to video), I'd check you have space in your $HOME (home directory), as GUI logins require the creation of work files, if they cannot be created - gui login fails & you're kicked out to greeter again without message.  Text terminal logins will proceed, so use that to verify you haven't filled your $HOME directory is my first check.

Comment: And how do I check that. ( I m a noob ) don't know how to.

Comment: I tried using startx, shows locked . Xauthority file, do I delete / can I delete it from Windows ?can't seem to access that via terminal after pressing alt ctrl F5 on Ubuntu login screen